# How to get marker position in pixel of image AR.JS?

Tags: ar.js

I want to integrate hand tracking to identify if a person clicked (like the mouse click event) on a marker or object. Maybe I just do not get the right way or workaround but I really want to get marker position in pixel.

```
marker.position()
```